# Get type of rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a user model.

`sample_user = User.all.first`

Is there a way in Ruby to get type back in a String? Something like:

`typeof(sample_user) == "User"`

Comment: sample_user.class.to_s == "User". Have you tried that??

Comment: you're right. i just tried it. it was easier than i thought.. i should have just googled it earlier :) woops

Answer (score 6):

```
sample_user.class.name
```

will give you "User"

Answer (score 6):

You can do it multiple ways :

1st :

```
sample_user.is_a? User
```

2nd :

```
sample_user.class.to_s == "User"
```

and more :). But if you want to check class type with object. Then 1st One would be good.

Comment: The language we are using believes in *duck typing*.. No type check.. if we do, it is insulting to *Ruby*.  :-) :-D

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing comparison, use `#kind_of?` or `#is_a?`

```
sample_user = User.first

sample_user.kind_of? User
#=> true

sample_user.is_a? User
#=> true
```